# What enables Alt+Click Window Dragging

Tags: kde, x, sddm

I use Kubuntu 18.04 and I wonder what component implements the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+ <kbd>Left Click</kbd> **drag**.

Does the **Display Manager SDDM** implement this, or is it the **X Server**, or is it something within **KDE**? I'm sorry I don't know how all of this works together.

**Background:** I would like to see additional functionality e.g. when <kbd>Alt</kbd>+ <kbd>Left Click</kbd> **drag** moves a maximized window, but once it moves it to another monitor, it does not maximize it again. If I can know who i.e. SDDM, X or whatever is implementing this, I can investigate further what I need to do to fix this issue. This is just the background but not the actual question here.

Comment: Window Manager handles shortcut keys, Xorg provide window related concepts.

Comment: Thank you. Is **Window Manager** same as the **Display Manager**? How do I find out what is the **Window Manager** in Kubuntu 18.04?

Comment: No, I believe the Window Manager of KDE is kwin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**KDE**(actually the **window manager** of **KDE**) receive the key/mouse/any input device event from Xorg, then decide to tell **Xorg** to move the window.

**Display Manager** does two things:

1. Authenticate your user with the password or any challenge.
2. Communicate with **Session Manager**(such as **systemd-logind** or  **ConsoleKit**) to create a session and give out seats to the session. It's a little complicated, just consider a seat as a bunch of input/output devices that can't be accessed by two different local sessions, like sound card/video output/keyboard/mouse.

Comment: Thank you. I got confused between **Window Manager** and the **Display Manager**. I was surprised that this functionality was there when they changed display managers from LightDM to SDDM, so I thought it may have been implemented somewhere else.